# Dual booting a new build. Which OS to install first, Windows or Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, gparted

I'm building my first desktop. I have this idea that I'm sort of obsessed with, and I think I need someone to tell me to calm down. I want to install Windows 8.1, update it, install drivers, install basic software and generally customize it until it suits me well, then install Ubuntu to dual boot, and then save an image of the entire 60GB SSD on my 1TB HDD?  Is there a way to copy multiple partitions (the entire SSD) and then save it as its own bootable recovery media on another drive?  Is it even worth doing? Am I over-thinking this?

Comment: Actually, you might be able to cut and paste the partitions using gparted if you do it right (boot from a live CD/USB first of all).  Making it bootable might be possible with GRUB if you know how.

Comment: But if an exact image, then you have duplicate UUIDs which are not allowed. Fine if copying to another system. Also if new system and you install in UEFI boot mode with gpt partitioning you should not image copy partitions. Entire drive is ok, but gpt partitions have even more internal data GUIDs that much not be duplicates and must match throughout drive. If you do it as an compressed image that you could restore then it may be ok.You should backup Windows as it takes a lot to install. But Ubuntu is easy to reinstall, so you only need to backup /home, some of /etc and list of installed apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is standard practice in many large organisations - you take a "clean" installation with everything set up correctly, then take basically a dump of the entire disk and store that in an image file, then when you deploy a new desktop you deploy from that image file.

You can basically do a `dd` of the whole drive, including all partitions, with, say

```
dd if=/dev/sdc of=/media/externalhd/myimage.img
```

Make sure none of the partitions are mounted, and you don't modify anything on the drive, during this operation (practically this means you should probably boot from a live CD/USB to do this).

> and then save it as it's own bootable reco media

Well one of the limitations of this practice is that you are copying the partition table and everything, so if you just do a straight restore onto another drive it has to be the same size or larger, and the partitions won't be resized - though you can do that later.